# Get all unique array combinations using Cartesian Product PHP

Tags: php, cartesian-product

I am trying to get all possible combinations for an unknown number of arrays as such:

**Here is the JSON data structure**

```
[
    {
        "department": "CIS",
        "name": "Intro to CIS",
        "sections": [
            {
                "sectionNumber": "01",
                "regNum": "012345",
                "days": "MWF",
                "startTime": "900",
                "endTime": "1030",
                "labDay": "M",
                "labStartTime": "1300",
                "labEndTime": "1500"
            },
            {
                "sectionNumber": "02",
                "regNum": "098304",
                "days": "TR",
                "startTime": "1300",
                "endTime": "1500",
                "labDay": "",
                "labStartTime": "",
                "labEndTime": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "department": "MATH",
        "name": "Intro to MATH",
        "sections": [
            {
                "sectionNumber": "01",
                "regNum": "012345",
                "days": "MWF",
                "startTime": "900",
                "endTime": "1030",
                "labDay": "M",
                "labStartTime": "1300",
                "labEndTime": "1500"
            },
            {
                "sectionNumber": "02",
                "regNum": "098304",
                "days": "TR",
                "startTime": "1300",
                "endTime": "1500",
                "labDay": "",
                "labStartTime": "",
                "labEndTime": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**I would like the result to be as follows: The result should contain the entire course associative array so that I can access all of its data (sectionNumber, regNum, days, ..etc)**

> Note, I do not know how many courses or sections there will be. Also, A course should never compare to itself.

*Desired Result:*

```
[
    [ [CIS 01 Array],[MATH 01 Array] ],
    [ [CIS 01 Array],[MATH 02 Array] ],
    [ [CIS 02 Array],[MATH 01 Array] ],
    [ [CIS 02 Array],[MATH 02 Array]]
]
```

Each result array should contain arrays (that are the same length as the number of courses) of arrays.

---

**I think I should be using the Cartesian Product, but I am not entirely sure on how to implement this.
I started to do something like this, but I know it is not correct:**

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_data); $i++){ //courses
    for($k = 0; $k < count($json_data[$i]["sections"]); $k++){ //first sections
        for($p = 1; $p < count($json_data[$i]["sections"]); $p++){ //all other courses but 1
            for($h = 0; $h < count($json_data[$i]["sections"][$p]); $h++){
                echo $json_data[$i]["sections"][$k]["labDay"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your memory constraints, you could use a recursive function that adds all remaining elements including itself to your results array.

Comment: @ChrisThorsvik But is should be the results array that holds arrays containing arrays. Also, a course should never compare to itself.

Comment: Can you clarify one thing? You said "Each result array should contain arrays...that are the same length as the number of courses". Did you mean that each element in the result array should contain exactly one course from each department?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic cross product solution (not mine, I found it somewhere, don't remember where but there's a bunch available online):

```
function crossProduct() {
    $_ = func_get_args();
    if (count($_) == 0) {
        return array(array());
    }                
    $a = array_shift($_);         
    $c = call_user_func_array('crossProduct', $_);        
    $r = array();
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        foreach ($c as $p) {
            $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
```

You will however need to pre-process your solution a bit:

```
$allDepartmentsSections = [];
foreach ($jsonArrayEntry as $entry) {
        $sections = [];
        foreach ($entry["section"] as $section) {
              $sections[] = $section + [ "department" => $entry["department"], "name"=>$entry["name"] ];
        } 
        $allDepartmentsSections[] = $sections;
}
```

You can then do:

```
call_user_func_array('crossProduct', $allDepartmentsSections);
```

See it working at https://3v4l.org/sSFpu

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
//simplified json for answer, you could use yours
$json = '[
    {
        "department": "CIS",
        "sections": [
            {
                "sectionNumber": "CIS-1"
            },
            {
                "sectionNumber": "CIS-2"
            }
        ]
    },{
        "department": "ENG",
        "sections": [
            {
                "sectionNumber": "ENG-1"
            },
            {
                "sectionNumber": "ENG-2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "department": "MATH",
        "sections": [
            {
                "sectionNumber": "MATH-1"
            },
            {
                "sectionNumber": "MATH-2"
            }
        ]
    }
]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);
$cartesian = [];

//Use array map to run over all array items
array_map(function($item) use($data, &$cartesian) {
    //starting from your element, search for all others "next departments"
    for($i = array_search($item, $data)+1, $c = count($data); $i<$c; $i++) {
        //foreach "next departments" get section
        foreach($data[$i]['sections'] as $section) {
            //foreach sections of current department, do
            foreach($item['sections'] as $item_section) {
                //append to cartesian resultset
                $cartesian[] = [$item_section, $section];
            }
        }
    }
}, $data);

//create a reverse array, to get all reverse combinations.
// Ex.: We have CIS-1 -> MATH-1, now we have MATH-1 -> CIS-1
$reverse = array_map('array_reverse', $cartesian);
//merge to cartesian resultset
$cartesian = array_merge($cartesian, $reverse);

print_r(count($cartesian)); print_r($cartesian);
```

Output:

```
24

    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-1
                )

        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => CIS-2
                )

        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-1
                )

        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => MATH-2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sectionNumber] => ENG-2
                )

        )

)
```